# Need mapping between TFS Team Name and Work Item Ids

Tags: sql-server, rest, tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS, every Team is associated with Project. Also every Team has their own work items. Team can have more than one area path, similarly one area path can be associated with more than one team. 
So I need to create a report where we can get all Work Items associated with specific team. 
Is there any way to get that mapping from any table from TFS databases or using REST API?

Answer (score 0):

No such report by default. You can add a custom field to represent teams in your organization, you can reconfigure the agile planning tools and pages to support your teams and decouple assignment to teams and area paths.

[image]

Detailed steps, you can follow MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn144940.aspx